# How to sync an offline Access database with SharePoint (WSS 3.0) List

Tags: wss-3.0

Is it possible to sync an offline Access database with a SharePoint (WSS 3.0) List?

How can I do a two way sync to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this tutorial:

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=68

Access 2007 will let you work Offline and synchronise when connection has restored.

Comment: Thanks! The article says its for "SharePoint Server 2007", will it work for WSS 3.0?

Comment: It should do, I think it uses the same synchronisation model as Excel, which does work in WSS3.0.

Comment: ok, I tried to move data, But I got error "the site you specified does not support importing data from microsoft office access database widows sharepoint services"